# Format date with jQuery calendar

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Using jQuery calendar we got date in `"04/05/2011"` format.

I want to convert this into `"Wed, 6th Apr 2011"`.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using any calendar plug-in? Or jQuery UI calendar? If you post your plug-in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the date in PHP just do something like this

```
$date = '04/05/2011';
$new_date = time('D, d M y', strtotime($date));
```

`$new_date` will now have the data as you want it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the datepicker from the jqueryui library.

You can set the format of the datepicker like this.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ altFormat: 'D, d M y' });
```

find more here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/